# Java JUnit assertEquals with Long

Tags: java, junit, long-integer

```
    assertEquals( new Long(42681241600) , new Long(42681241600) );
```

I am try to check two long numbers but when i try to compile this i get

```
    integer number too large: 42681241600
```

error. Documentation shows there is a Long,Long assertEquals method but it is not called.

Answer (score 21):

You want:

```
assertEquals(42681241600L, 42681241600L);
```

Your code was calling assertEquals(Object, Object).  You also needed to append the 'L' character at the end of your numbers, to tell the Java compiler that the number should be compiled as a long instead of an int.

Answer (score 7):

42681241600 is interpreted as an `int` literal, which it is too large to be. Append an 'L' to make it a `long` literal.

If you want to get all technical, you can look up [§3.10.1 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` [(§4.2.1)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#9151). The suffix `L` is preferred, because the letter `l` (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit `1` (one).

Answer (score 6):

You should also generally consider using Long.valueOf since this may allow some optimisation:

```
Long val = Long.valueOf(1234L);
```

From the [J2SDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long)):

> public static Long valueOf(long l)
>
> Returns a Long instance representing
>   the specified long value. If a new
>   Long instance is not required, this
>   method should generally be used in
>   preference to the constructor
>   Long(long), as this method is likely
>   to yield significantly better space
>   and time performance by caching
>   frequently requested values.

Answer (score 2):

append an "L" at the end of your number, like:

```
new Long(42681241600L)
```

in Java, every literal number is treated as an integer.